# jquery passing string reference to object as parameter to function

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure wether to pass an $(object) or a string referencing the name of an object to a function:

```
function makeObject(div){
    var newDiv = $(div);
    $(div).html("newDiv: " + newDiv);
    }
```

and caller:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<a href="#" onclick="makeObject($(this).parent().attr('id'));">makeObject(this</a>
</div>
```

I hope this is clear. It's a test function to get the principle in my head. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a valid selector, in case of `id` selector add `#` prefix in the string.

```
onclick="makeObject('#' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));"
```

---

Or simply pass the parent element jQuery object. In this case, you don't need to wrap it using jQuery again inside the function.

```
onclick="makeObject($(this).parent());"
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a more elegant solution. I used $(this).parent().attr('id') so I could copy/paste the code and not worry about id's but your right I don't need the attr('id') again. Useful.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also add event handler on click.

```
// $(".myA").click(function (e) {
$("#myDiv").on("click", "a", function(e) {
```

```js
// $(".myA").click(function (e) {
$("#myDiv").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  console.log(this); // `this` is anchor element

  var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  console.log(parentId);

  e.preventDefault();
});

function makeObject(div) {
  var newDiv = $(div);
  $(div).html("newDiv: " + newDiv);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">
  <a href="#" class="myA">
makeObject(this);
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! This way, I'm sure there is a more elegant answer but:
    `function makeObject(div){
    var newDiv = {};//$(div);
    newDiv = $("#"+div+"");
    newDiv.html("newDiv: " + newDiv);
   }`
and function call:
    `<div id="myDiv"><a href="#" onclick="makeObject($(this).parent().attr('id'));" >makeObject(this);</a></div>`